# Custom element index page (cp) sortable on dateCreated?

Tags: plugin-development, element

I have a plugin with custom elements that can be sorted on a handful of fields in my CP element index page. I can get the DATECREATED displaying correctly that Craft generates automatically but I cannot sort by it. I am getting an ambiguous column error in SQL and not sure how I am supposed to include these native columns so they can be sorted like in the CP entries section. The other field, SCORE, is an example of one of my fields that I adjust the html display a bit (add a '%' sign) when it's rendered and sorting doesn't seem to work. Anybody with some tips? I tried referencing the craft app EntryElementType file but still could not quite figure it out. Thanks

```
public function defineSortableAttributes()
{
    $attributes = array(
        'id'            => Craft::t('ID'), 
        'userId'        => Craft::t('User'), 
        'testId'        => Craft::t('Test ID'),  
        'score'         => Craft::t('Score'), // no errors but not sorting properly
        'dateCreated'   => Craft::t('Date Created'), 
    );

    return $attributes;
}

/**
 * Returns the attributes that can be shown/sorted by in table views.
 *
 * @param string|null $source
 * @return array
 */
public function defineAvailableTableAttributes()
{
    $attributes = array(
        'id'                => Craft::t('ID'), 
        'userId'            => Craft::t('User'), 
        'testId'            => Craft::t('Test'), 
        'results'           => Craft::t('Results'), 
        'score'             => Craft::t('Score'), 
        'ipAddress'         => Craft::t('IP Address'), 
        'dateCreated'       => Craft::t('Date Created'), 
    );

    return $attributes;
}
```

The error for dateCreated (when trying to sort by the field) is below. When trying to sort by SCORE I don't notice an error but the order doesn't seem to change, so I'm not terribly sure what's not quite right there. Maybe something to do with sorting on fields where I customize the html output?

```
CDbException
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'dateCreated' in order clause is ambiguous. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `elements`.`id`, `elements`.`type`, `elements`.`enabled`, `elements`.`archived`, `elements`.`dateCreated`, `elements`.`dateUpdated`, `elements_i18n`.`slug`, `elements_i18n`.`uri`, `elements_i18n`.`enabled` AS `localeEnabled`, `ts`.* FROM `craft_elements` `elements` JOIN `craft_elements_i18n` `elements_i18n` ON elements_i18n.elementId = elements.id JOIN `craft_testcenter_submissions` `ts` ON ts.id = elements.id WHERE (elements_i18n.locale = :locale) AND (elements.archived = 0) GROUP BY `elements`.`id` ORDER BY `dateCreated` ASC LIMIT 50. Bound with :locale='en_us' (/volume1/storage/___/HTML/01/craft/app/framework/db/CDbCommand.php:543)
```

Here is my modifyElementsQuery

```
public function modifyElementsQuery(DbCommand $query, ElementCriteriaModel $criteria)
{
    $query
        ->addSelect('ts.*')
        ->join('testcenter_submissions ts', 'ts.id = elements.id');

    if ($criteria->userId)
    {
        $query->andWhere(DbHelper::parseParam('ts.userId', $criteria->userId, $query->params));
    }

    if ($criteria->testId)
    {
        $query->andWhere(DbHelper::parseParam('ts.testId', $criteria->testId, $query->params));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us the exact error? When I copy your code into my custom element type it is working fine

Comment: Updated with SQL error ;)

Comment: Do you have a custom `dateCreated` column/attribute in record for `craft_testcenter_submissions`? Craft usually takes care for all `dateCreated` attributes and the SQL states it does not know which column to take

Comment: I have my own table where these custom fields (like score etc) are saved and Craft automatically created a few of the usual columns like dateCreated, dateUpdated and uid. The dateCreated field in my craft_testcenter_submissions table is the one I am trying to use. It gets displayed properly but when sorting Craft doesn't know which dateCreated to use and I'm not quite sure how to remedy.

Comment: Did you change the `modifyElementsQuery` function somehow?

Comment: Yes a small bit. I'll add it to original post.

Comment: Hmmmm...I think I see where you are going with this, I am grabbing all ts.* columns which includes dateCreated. How can I specify thats the one I want to use vs the elements' dateCreated?

Comment: simply by not selecting all columns `ts.*` but only those you need `ts.score`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense but I am actually using the dateCreated from this table not from the element. I don't believe changing the elements dateCreated etc cascades to these records which I why I wanted to display ts.dateCreated for example instead of the elements' dateCreated. I updated to only select specific ts.xxxxxx fields vs * but unless I can alias that field as a new name like myDateCreated I may have to rethink how I am using dateCreated. If I include ts.dateCreated I will of course still have the same ambiguos column issue.

Comment: Then you might want to change your logic while storing your records. Craft usually takes care of everything. You `testcenter_submissions``dateCreated` and `dateUpdated` fields should always be the same as those from the `craft_elements` table. Maybe you don't use `craft()->element->saveElement()`?

Comment: Okay, I can do that. I know I was using some logic to see how old a custom element was (based on dateCreated) and was manually changing that field for testing. I can refactor, that makes sense. Any thoughs on the scoring sorting? The values are stored like 100, 66.7, 33.3, 50 etc and I am just adding a percent sign in the tablehtml. I'm not getting an error but it also doesn't seem to change the order.

Comment: As I already said.. Craft/SQL handles everything. As long as you have an `numeric` column type you don't have to do anything else than adding the correct index in your `defineSortableAttributes` in your case it could be `ts.score` edit: of course that's only the case if you don't changed the `getIndexHtml` as well

Comment: Thanks Robin. If you respond the select '*' was a conflict with the elements dateCreated I'll mark as the answer. I'm definitely fighting something odd/unrelated with the score column. Others work as expected but that one doesn't change the sorting whether asc/desc and it isn't actually asc or desc. The arrow will change from asc/desc but even the options if you choose the sorting dropdown on the right ascending/descending are grayed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the `modifyElementsQuery` function. When you select all columns `addSelect('*')` to the query your `SQL` will select the `dateCreated` and `dateUpdated` columns of your custom table as well. 
As soon as you want to order by one of those columns the database does not know which `dateCreated` should be sorted.

You need to select only the unique attribute columns in your custom element table.

To debug your `score` sorting issue the best thing is to go into `craft/app/elementtypes/BaseElementType.php` and check the function `getIndexHtml`. You can `var_dump` the results of the following variables

```
// Combine them, accounting for the possibility that $order could contain multiple values,
// and be defensive about the possibility that the first value actually has "asc" or "desc"

// typeId             => typeId [sort]
// typeId, title      => typeId [sort], title
// typeId, title desc => typeId [sort], title desc
// typeId desc        => typeId [sort]

$criteria->order = preg_replace('/^(.*?)(?:\s+(?:asc|desc))?(,.*)?$/i', "$1 {$sort}$2", $order);
```

and compare the output with default Entry fields.

Comment: Thanks Robin, this was the answer/issues.... As you referenced I was getting dateCreated in element vs my own table confused, and using the ts.* made a conflict of selecting both. As far as SCORE, it would appear it must have been conflicting with a Craft score. When I renamed to testScore it started sorting properly. Robin's response regarding getIndexHtml led me to noticing Craft had a native score and I think therein lied the conflict. It is now working exactly as expected.